# How do I choose a category page to be the home page for a Pelican site?

Tags: python, static-site, pelican

I would like the visitors to my site to land on a category page, not on the default `index.html`. I want them to see the articles in the News categories before anything else.

Maybe is there a way to tell Pelican to output `category/news` to `index.html`? I know this would be possible with normal handwritten pages using the `save_as` field, but how can I do it with an automatic page generated by Pelican?

Comment: Do you mean to have a static page as the home page?

http://docs.getpelican.com/en/4.0.1/faq.html#how-can-i-use-a-static-page-as-my-home-page

Comment: No, I mean a Category page, which Pelican generates automatically. I browsed the Pelican source code and it doesn't seem to allow plug-in intervention before rendering DIRECT_TEMPLATES. Although I think I found some other leads to change Category save_as even before rendering DIRECT_TEMPLATES. Not sure yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your homepage, the `index.html` file, is just another template from the [`DIRECT_TEMPLATES` list](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#template-pages). It'll depend on your theme exactly how it is generated, but you can always override specific templates locally, *or* you can create a new template for your homepage to replace it (and optionally redirect the original `index.html` generated page to a different location).

Either way, you can then generate a section that shows the articles from a single category. All template pages are given the same [basic variables](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html#common-variables), which includes the `articles` list, as well as a `categories` list with `(Category, list_of_articles)` tuples.

The easiest way to get all articles for a single, specific category is to filter the `articles` list directly with the Jinja2 [`selectattr` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#selectattr). `selectattr('category', '==', categoryname)` is matched both against the category name or the slug (whatever you set `categoryname` to is converted to a slug for you). So if your category is named `News`, then both `'News'` or `'news'` works:

```html
<h2>News:</h2>
<ol id="posts-list" class="hfeed">
{% for article in articles | selectattr('category', '==', 'news') %}
    <li><article class="hentry">
        <header>
            <h1><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" rel="bookmark"
                   title="Permalink to {{ article.title|striptags }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
        {% include 'article_infos.html' %}
        {{ article.summary }}
        <a class="readmore" href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">read more</a>
        {% include 'comments.html' %}
        </div><!-- /.entry-content -->
    </article></li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

The above reuses the simple theme article markup. You may want to limit the number of news articles; in that case use the [`batch(size)` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#batch) together with [`first`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#first):

```html
<h2>News:</h2>

<ol id="posts-list" class="hfeed">
{% for article in articles | selectattr('category', '==', 'news') | batch(5) | first %}
    <!-- render article, etc. -->
```

The above takes the first 5 articles with `News` as the category.

Since the basic theme *reuses* the `index.html` template for all of the individual archive pages too (for each category, author or tag page), I'd not override the `index` direct template here. Instead, I'd create a *new* `homepage` template (in the pages directory) and write that to `index.html` and. You need to add the template in the [`TEMPLATE_PAGES` dictionary](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#template-pages), where your template pages should live in a separate directory that is configured not to be treated as articles or pages.

Create a new directory for *template pages* in your content directory; you'll need to make sure Pelican doesn't try to treat files there as articles, so add it to the [`ARTICLE_EXCLUDES` list](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#basic-settings). So if all your Pelican your content lives in `content/`, and you have a file `homepage.html` in the directory `output/templates/`, you'd use:

```
ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = ['templates']
TEMPLATE_PAGES = {
    'templates/homepage.html': 'index.html',
}
```

This will overwrite the default `index.html` generated for articles, there is no need to remove anything from `DIRECT_TEMPLATES` but you could do so to avoid generating a file you never keep.

The `homepage.html` template can make full use of any existing templates in the theme, so you can just extend `base.html` that most themes will have defined:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<section id="content">

<h2>Recent news:</h2>
<ol>
{% for article in articles | selectattr('category', 'equalto', 'news') | batch(5) | first %}

    <!-- markup for each news item -->

{% endfor %}
</ol>

</section><!-- /#content -->
{% endblock content %}
```

Instead of overwriting the default `index`, you can also set [`INDEX_SAVE_AS`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#url-settings) to direct the original `index.html` file elsewhere:

```
ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = ['templates']
TEMPLATE_PAGES = {
    'pages/homepage.html': 'index.html',
}
# move the original article index elsewhere:
INDEX_SAVE_AS = 'all_articles.html'
```

If you use a theme that doesn't reuse the `index.html` template for more pages or you want to try to make the template work for in those contexts anyway, then you can override the template used for `index` instead. To override the default `index.html` from your theme, create a local directory (`overrides` perhaps) to put your local version into, then add that directory to the [`THEME_TEMPLATES_OVERRIDES` list](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#themes) in your configuration:

```
THEME_TEMPLATES_OVERRIDES = ['overrides']
```

Now when Pelican tries to load the `index.html` template to render the `index` direct template, it'll look for `overrides/index.html` first. So in `overrides/` add your own `index.html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<section id="content">

<!-- put your desired content here -->

</section><!-- /#content -->
{% endblock content %}
```

A word on pagination: all templates, except for the special per-archive-type pages (categories, authors, tags, periods), are paginated on the full `articles` list, this isn't something that is further configurable. This means you can't paginate a homepage on a single category of articles.

This means that if you override the `index.html` template and removed the full article listing, then you may want to remove `index` from the [`PAGINATED_TEMPLATES`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#pagination) dictionary so it isn't re-generated multiple times to match your article list.

Comment: templates are searched in the templates/ directory so TEMPLATE_PAGES = {'homepage.html': 'index.html',}

Comment: @PizzaBeer I am confused about paths: where should I put the files? What are the references for relative path.

Comment: @M.Toya limited docs, source is hard to read.  All I know is it works for me.  My guess is this behavior is inside Jinja2, not pelican.  My structure is as follows: ./theme/templates/subdir/my.html and ./pelicanconf.py.  In the pelicanconf.py I have TEMPLATE_PAGES = {'subdir/my.html': 'index.html',} .  If I say 'templates/subdir/my.html' I get a TemplateNotFound